# ItemTouchHelper throws IndexOutOfBoundException while trying to swap items

Tags: kotlin

I have a RecyclerView that adds items which should be dragged & dropped, however, when an item gets added and i try to swap it an IndexOutOfBoundException get thrown

The RecyclerView observes a ViewModel that refreshes information when some block gets added, i've used LiveData to achieve it.

My solution works perfectly fine when the list has a set number of items, the problem arises when i try to add something to the RecyclerView.

I've extended the ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallBack with a class that contains
the adapter for the RecyclerView, but when items get added the size strangely doesn't change(i've tried to set it manually but it won't work).

Iv've tried to detach the TouchHelper by calling

touchHelper?.attachToRecyclerView(null)

and then attaching it again with a new callback but it won't work either.

this is the acitvity

```
class CreateWorkflowActivity: AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    var touchHelper:ItemTouchHelper?= null
    private lateinit var callback:ItemMoveCallback
    private lateinit var rec_view: RecyclerView
    companion object {
        private lateinit var viewModel : WorkflowViewModel
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_workflow)
        val factory= InjectorUtils.provideWorkflowViewModelFactory("")
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,factory).get(WorkflowViewModel::class.java)
        rec_view= findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_addedBlocksOnCreation)
        rec_view.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val observer = Observer<ArrayList<String>>{
            val adapter = BlockViewAdapter(it!!, this@CreateWorkflowActivity)
            callback= ItemMoveCallback(adapter,this@CreateWorkflowActivity,ItemTouchHelper.UP.or(ItemTouchHelper.DOWN),0)
            touchHelper= ItemTouchHelper(callback)
            touchHelper?.attachToRecyclerView(rec_view)
            runOnUiThread{
                rec_view.adapter= adapter
            }
        }
        viewModel.getLiveBlockNames().observe(this,observer)


    }

//this gets called when the user has decided the parameters for the block
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK) {

               //all block additions

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

this extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallBack

```
class ItemMoveCallback(adapter: BlockViewAdapter, context: Context, dragDirs: Int, swipeDirs: Int) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(dragDirs, swipeDirs)
{
    var mAdapter = adapter


    override fun onSwiped(p0: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        return
    }

    override fun onMove(p0: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
        mAdapter.swapItems(viewHolder.adapterPosition, target.adapterPosition)
        return true
    }
    fun setAdapter(adapter: BlockViewAdapter){
        mAdapter=adapter
    }

}
```

This is the adapter (i've omitted the BlockViewHolder because it's pretty standard)

```
class BlockViewAdapter(val dataset: ArrayList<String>,val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<BlockViewHolder>(){

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BlockViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.tView?.text = dataset[position]

        }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataset.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BlockViewHolder {

        return BlockViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.block_item,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    }

    fun swapItems(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {

        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            for (i in fromPosition..toPosition - 1) {
                dataset.set(i, dataset.set(i+1, dataset.get(i)))
            }
        } else {
            for (i in fromPosition..toPosition + 1) {
                dataset.set(i, dataset.set(i-1, dataset.get(i)))
            }
        }

        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ludovico Brocca You are running into `IndexOutOfBoundException` because you are not calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you add new item to the adapter.

So, initialize your adapter with just context then have the items as setter.
Example below for reference:

```
class BlockViewAdapter(val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BlockViewHolder>() {

    var dataset: List<String> = emptyList()
      set(value) {
        // might have to do this on main thread
        field = value
        notifyDataSetChanged()
      }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BlockViewHolder {
      TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BlockViewHolder, position: Int) {
      TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
      TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

  }
```